# psycopg2: Offline installation doesn't work, import error

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, package, psycopg2

I want to install psycopg2 on an offline system. I used

```
pip3 install psycopg2 -t ./ --system
```

on my online pc to get the module and copied it to the offline pc in the directory of my to-be-executed python file.

The problem is the following:

```
ImportError: module not found in line 50: psycopg2._psycopg2
```

(That error paraphrased from my memory)

I then proceeded to install [this .deb package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/xenial/python-psycopg2) and its depending debs, but it didn't change anything.

The offline system is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS where as my online system where I can download files is running on 18.04 LTS.

How am I going to find the problem here?

Kind regards

Comment: Did you try to just download the correct `whl` file on you online PC and then copy it to your offline PC for installation?

Comment: I couldn't find a wheel file for linux, but for `psycopg2-binary` there is one and it works. I had to download python-pip3 and its dependencies and install those debs on the offline machine.